# Reminder entries duplicated after updating from iOS 6 to iOS 7

Tags: ios6, ios7, duplicates, icloud, icalendar

I have one iPhone application in which I have integrated the iCloud & reminder. Till iOS 6 its working correctly. After updating iOS to 7 , users of my app complaining about duplicate entries in reminders app of iOS.

Users of my app synched the data to iCloud & after that they got duplicate entries in Reminders app. I checked for API deprecation. But my app is not using any deprecated API from Event Kit Framework.

Does anybody face this issue or have any idea why this is happening in the application ?

I checked the below links where users faced the same issue but on previous version of iOS

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1252694

http://eliteeternity.com/ios5-update-calendar-events-duplicated-easy-fix/

Thanks in advance.